# jQuery resets textarea on any click, but is said to only do so when the textarea has a certain value

Tags: jquery, textarea, reset

I'm currently experiencing a problem. I'm trying to reset my textarea, if it has the value `Message...`(which it has when you load the page). But as it is now, it resets no matter what value it has. Here's my jquery code:

```
if ($("#text").value = 'Message...') 
{
    $("#text").click(function () {
        $(this).val('');
    });
}
```

The HTML code is just a textarea inside a form.

Comment: Don't use the text.click part. It's causing any click on that form element to reset the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few of your problems are that

```
if ($("#text").value = 'Message...') 
// should be replaced with the line below
if ($(this).val() == 'Message...')
```

Notice the use of `val()` instead of `value` and instead of the assignment operator, I used the equality operator (you could also the identity operator `===`).

Also, the reason why your text is always being reset is because your event handler is resetting the text each time you click the `#text` element, so to achieve the expected behavior you need to wrap the logic inside the event handler.

```
$("#text").click(function () {
  if ($(this).val() == 'Message...')
    $(this).val('');
 });
```

If you wanted to achieve a "placeholder" effect you could use the following instead:

```
$("#text").focusin(function () {
  if ($(this).val() == 'Message...')
    $(this).val('');
}).focusout(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == '')
    $(this).val('Message...');
});
```

Comment: Used half of your code: I deleted the focusout (because I don't need it) function and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`$("#text").value = 'Message...'` will always be **true** because you're using the assignment operator. use `===` instead for comparison.

```
if ($("#text").val() === 'Message...') 
{
    $("#text").click(function () {
        $(this).val('');
    });
}
```

Comment: the jQuery object also doesn't have a `value` property.